# send push notifications over azure

Tags: windows, azure, push-notification, uwp

How can i send a push notificattion over azure from my UWP-App to other instances of my app on different devices?

Here is the explanation of registering your device for receiving push. (This works)
The second part is about how to send a push over a console application (This works also)
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-windows-store-dotnet-get-started/

When I want to import "Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs" with NuGet which seems necessary for sending push I get an error message which says that this package is not compüatible with Windows 10 UAP.

I know that I am using an outdatet version of the documentation but I can't find anything newer...

What am I doing wrong? Any experiences here?

Comment: That tutorial you linked isn't for a Win10 UWP app (it's for 8.1).

Comment: Yes I know. But can you provide me something like this tutorial for win 10

Answer (score 0):

You are using an out of date guide for Windows 8.1, not Windows 10/UWP.

Here is an updated guide from Mirosoft: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt187203.aspx